# How does a RewriteRule work when the first argument is just a dot?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I installed some PHP software that added the following to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

What is this doing?

My interpretation, which is obviously wrong: It's capturing `http://foo.bar.com` as `http:` and `foo.bar.com`, then replacing any character, `.`, with `http:/foo.bar.com`. Definitely not, right?

Comment: %{REQUEST_URI} doesn't match domain ,it is  %{HTTP_HOST} to match foo.bar.com , let me know what you need ?

Comment: Ah, okay. Then I was wrong. But regardless, I'm trying to understand what it does. Why would there ever be double forward slashes?

Comment: This code really give me new techniques to be applied to enhance user experience level  so,when user adds some slash by mistake , he should go correctly  , many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's capturing `http://foo.bar.com` as `http:` and `foo.bar.com`, then replacing any character, `.`, with `http:/foo.bar.com`. Definitely not, right?

Right, definitely not. :)

That code reduces multiple slashes that appear together in the URL-path to a single slash. So a URL like `example.com/foo//bar////baz` becomes `example.com/foo/bar/baz`.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the URL-path only (starting with a slash). eg. `/foo//bar////baz` (in the above example). `%1` and `%2` are backreferences to the captured groups in the last matched *CondPattern* (ie. the strings either side of a double slash).

The single dot (`.`) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches a single character. So this rule matches every URL, except the document root, when the URL-path is empty.

**Why check for multiple slashes?** If these are requests for physical files then Apache will implicitly reduce multiple slashes in order to serve the resource. So `/foo//bar////baz.html` will return the same as `/foo/bar/baz.html`. So, that's "good". However, these are technically different URLs, so this could be perceived as *duplicate content* by search engines. It could also break your application, if you are parsing the URL for other purposes. This may or may not be a problem. This would require users to link to you incorrectly etc. (unless something broke in your web app that resulted in these URLs being generated.)

---

I would add that this method isn't particularly efficient as it requires multiple external redirects if you have many additional slashes (although you could argue that this is only intended to cache edge cases anyway). For example, given a request for `/foo//bar////baz`, the following redirects will occur:

1. `/foo//bar////baz` (Initial request / redirect)
2. `/foo//bar///baz` (redirect)
3. `/foo//bar//baz` (redirect)
4. `/foo//bar/baz` (redirect)
5. `/foo/bar/baz`

Comment: Oh, I see. The first `RewriteRule` arg isn't a regex to be substituted, but a regex to filter the set of URLs to convert to the second arg. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ restricts the URLs that the directive applies to. Ideally, this should be as restrictive as possible - this is the first thing that is processed, before the `RewriteCond` directive that precedes it in the file. I've added a bit to my answer about "why" you might to check for multiple slashes in the URL.

Comment: You can reduce all slashes in one time (but in one place) just with `RewriteRule ^(.*)//+(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]`.

Comment: @Croises Yes, well, kind of... you'll still need to use a `RewriteCond` directive and check against the `REQUEST_URI` var since the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` matches against already has the slashes _reduced_. You will also need to make the captured groups non-greedy, otherwise they will match slashes as well and there will be no improvement. eg. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)//+(.*?)$` - but this still only matches _single_ groups of slashes. For `/foo////bar////baz` there will still be 2 redirects. However, you can avoid this by using internal rewrites and only redirect at the end.

Comment: Very well explained +1. I have posted a solution to remove all multiple slashes in a single redirect rule below.

Answer (score 3):

[MrWhite has explained very nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46585659/548225) interpretation of the rule you have in question. However there is still a problem when a URL with multiple slashes is sent over to your web server e.g. `/foo//bar////baz`. Your rule would cause 5 redirects before resolving it to `/foo/bar/baz`.

There is some discussion in comments section below his answer on what should be the rule to get this done in a single redirect.

Here is a rule that will remove all multiple slash URLs into a single slash URL in a **single redirect**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]
```

It uses back-reference of matched pattern from `RewriteRule` directive which already gets multiple slash free match by `mod_rewrite` engine.